# How to call java method from p:contextMenu

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable which is used to display array list of objects. I want to add `p:contextMenu` in order to click with the right button and to remove row from the table. I added the `p:contextMenu` on the top of the table but I cannot call properly `bean.selectedIds[item.comp]` in order to send the unique I. How I can solve the problem?
When I add `p:contextMenu` into the table body it's not working.

```
<h:form id="form" >

    <p:contextMenu for="dataTable">
        <p:menuitem value="View" update="dataTable" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="dataTable" actionListener="#{bean.selectedIds}"/>
    </p:contextMenu>

    <!-- The sortable data table -->
    <h:dataTable id="dataTable" headerClass="columnHeader" value="#{bean.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
        <!-- Check box -->
        <h:column>

            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this);" value="#{bean.selectedIds[item.comp]}" />

        </h:column>
        <!-- Row number -->
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="№" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{table.rowIndex + bean.firstRow + 1}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink value="comp ID" actionListener="#{bean.sort}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">
                    <f:attribute name="sortField" value="comp" />
                    <f:ajax render="@form" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.comp}" />
        </h:column>
        ........

    </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<p:datatable` ?

Comment: Because I have custom datatable.

Comment: add <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedIds}" value="#{item}" /> between your <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this);" />. did you try this?